# How to CloudDeploy a Manipulatable learned PredictorFunction?

Tags: cloud-deploy, machine-learning

Consider the following combination of `Manipulate` and learned `PredictorFunction`:

```
trainingset = {1 -> 1.3, 2 -> 2.4, 3 -> 4.4, 4 -> 5.1, 6 -> 7.3};
predictorFunction = Predict[trainingset];
Manipulate[predictorFunction[x], {x, 1, 6}]
```

It works great in the notebook.

[image]

[But when I `CloudDeploy` it sadly does not work :(](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/5dc11347-2ee8-497a-af81-57e3f295f2a7)

```
CloudDeploy[
 trainingset = {1 -> 1.3, 2 -> 2.4, 3 -> 4.4, 4 -> 5.1, 6 -> 7.3};
 predictorFunction = Predict[trainingset];
 Manipulate[predictorFunction[x], {x, 1, 6}]
  , Permissions -> "Public"
]
```

## Question

> ### How do I convert a learned `PredictorFunction` into an equivalent function that works when `CloudDeploy`-ed

Comment: This works for me on M12.2. Which version of M are you using to deploy the object to cloud? When I try to interact with your deployed object I see this error towards the end of error messages: "Message[LibraryFunction::notfound, \
"/home/conor/mathematica/SystemFiles/Links/DAALLink/\
LibraryResources/Linux-x86-64/DAALLink.so"]".

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `InterpolationFunction`s are `Manipulate`-able in a `CloudDeploy`.

Thus one work-around is to sample some data from the `PredictorFunction` and then use `Interpolation` to approximate the `PredictorFunction` with an `InterpolationFunction`.

```
CloudDeploy[
 trainingset = {1 -> 1.3, 2 -> 2.4, 3 -> 4.4, 4 -> 5.1, 6 -> 7.3};
 predictorFunction = Predict[trainingset];
 interpolationFunction = Interpolation@Table[{x, predictorFunction[x]}, {x, 1, 6}];
 
 Manipulate[interpolationFunction[x], {x, 1, 6}]

  , Permissions -> "Public"]
```

https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/7513658e-ef9e-4c2d-a0d6-369ac2d043d7

[image]